# "This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()" / calling `exec` on QDialog subclass

Tags: python, pyqt5, pytest, qdialog, pytest-qt

NB OS is **W10**.

The context here is pytest-qt. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074229/595305) and tried to use it (see later).

I get this error when a test method calls an application method which creates a `QFileDialog` and then calls `exec` on it. The console then puts out this message and the console hangs. I have no option but to close the console manually.

One factor involved here is this setting (set during testing before running the test):

```
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM'] = 'offscreen'
```

... without this line the `QFileDialog` displays OK on `exec`, the test concludes, and the console does not hang.

I don't of course know which plugin is the culprit... having googled on "propagateSizeHints" nothing came up. `pip freeze` output is as follows:

```
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.2.0
colorama==0.4.4
coloredlogs==15.0.1
concurrent-log-handler==0.9.19
humanfriendly==10.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
packaging==21.2
pluggy==1.0.0
portalocker==2.3.2
py==1.11.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PyQt5==5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
pyreadline3==3.3
pytest==6.2.5
pytest-qt==4.0.2
pywin32==302
toml==0.10.2
```

Having searched instead on problems with `exec` I found the above answer by eyllanesc. So I tried this:

```
def test_file_dialog_should_do_x(request, qtbot):
    t_logger.info(f'\n>>>>>> test name: {request.node.originalname}')
    main_win = main_window.AutoTransMainWindow() 
    proj = project.Project(main_win)
    def on_timeout():
        proj.modify_working_files()
        print('A1')
        assert proj.file_dlg.windowTitle() == 'Nonsense'
        print('A2')
    print('A3')
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, on_timeout)
    print('A4')
    assert proj.file_dlg.windowTitle() == 'Nonsense'
```

(These asserts are meant to fail)

The app code is as simple as possible:

```
def modify_working_files(self):
    self.file_dlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
    self.file_dlg.exec()
```

... but I again get the same "This plugin does not..." message, and the console again hangs. Only "A3" and "A4" get printed out.

One solution might be just to mock out `exec` universally. But eyllanesc knows his onions, and presumably would have said so if this were the case. And if it were the case I don't see how it would be possible to do any testing made possible by `qtbot`.

So far I've had no problems with the "offscreen" setting. But maybe there are limitations... [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1875621#p1875621) seems to suggest this might the root of the problem.

MRE:

```
import os

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM'] = 'offscreen'

QtWidgets.QApplication([])

class MainWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    pass

class Project():
    def __init__(self, main_win):
        self.main_win = main_win
        
    def modify_working_files(self):
        self.file_dlg = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
        self.file_dlg.exec()        
        
        
def test_file_dialog_should_do_x(request, qtbot):
    print(f'\n>>>>>> test name: {request.node.originalname}')
    
    main_win = MainWin() 
    proj = Project(main_win)
    def on_timeout():
        proj.modify_working_files()
        print('A1')
        assert proj.file_dlg.windowTitle() == 'Nonsense'
        print('A2')
    print('A3')
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, on_timeout)
    print('A4')
    assert proj.file_dlg.windowTitle() == 'Nonsense'
```

On my machine this produces (as expected) a FAIL on the line in function `on_timeout` if the QT_QPA_PLATFORM line is commented out.

If the latter is not commented out I get the plugin error message and the console hang.

Even if `MainWin` is made to `show()` in its constructor, and even if `QFileDialog` is created with `QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self.main_win)`, the error still happens.

I also tried `class Project(object)` and even (longshot) `class Project(QtCore.QObject)`. No joy.

NB I also searched, in all files in my virtual environment, and all files in my core Python installation (v. 3.9.4) for the string "propagatesize". Nothing!

Answer (score 1):

The source of this message appears to be [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/kernel/qplatformwindow.cpp.html):

```
void QPlatformWindow::propagateSizeHints() {qWarning("This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()"); }
```

So it's about using PyQt5 (or Qt5) on a Windows platform. It would appear from my experiments that it is a symptom but not a cause of the failure noted. Unfortunately [this page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/classes.html#q), which is meant to list "all Qt5 classes" (not just PyQt5) doesn't include it.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35902894/595305), this specific message can be suppressed by putting this in a file imported by all test files:

```
def qt_message_handler(mode, context, message):
    if mode == QtCore.QtInfoMsg:
        mode = 'INFO'
    elif mode == QtCore.QtWarningMsg:
        mode = 'WARNING'
        if 'propagateSizeHints' in message:
            return
    elif mode == QtCore.QtCriticalMsg:
        mode = 'CRITICAL'
    elif mode == QtCore.QtFatalMsg:
        mode = 'FATAL'
    else:
        mode = 'DEBUG'
    print('qt_message_handler: line: %d, func: %s(), file: %s' % (
          context.line, context.function, context.file))
    print('  %s: %s\n' % (mode, message))

QtCore.qInstallMessageHandler(qt_message_handler)
```

To overcome the problem of `exec`, the following counts as a workaround. I note from the Qt5 docs:

[QDialog.exec()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec)

> Note: Avoid using this function; instead, use open(). Unlike exec(),
> open() is asynchronous, and does not spin an additional event loop.
> This prevents a series of dangerous bugs from happening (e.g. deleting
> the dialog's parent while the dialog is open via exec()). When using
> open() you can connect to the finished() signal of QDialog to be
> notified when the dialog is closed.

Swapping this in, I still get the message "This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()"... but the console does not hang.

`exec()` returns an `int` value, but `open` doesn't. A small price to pay to get over this.

BUT... in fact, on my machine, `open` always results in a non-modal dialog, even if I `setModal(True)` (before it).

Fortunately `show()` honours `setModal(...)` ... and also does not cause the console to crash. Seems the one to use.

Comment: show() still causes the warning